# React Dropdwown Multilevel

Tags: reactjs

tengo que realizar un dropdown multilevel(pueden ser 2,3,o hasta 4 niveles) con React con informacion que viene del back end(pero por el momento con data fake que simule la misma estructura que venga del back estaria bien). Alguien me podria guiar para poder realizarlo?
Gracias

Comment: Si compartes tu código con mucho gusto te podemos ayudar. Para usar con react y hacer una implementación rápida y sencilla puedes utilizar [bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) o  [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/).

Comment: me pasaron este link http://jsfiddle.net/4snay57t/6/ . Mi codigo lo que tiene unicamente es el html de react bootstrap y por lo que vi es la estructura de la respuesta, pero dsp estoy atascado con el problema.